# Using Promise constructor to transform each element in an array and return the element back

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, geocoding, es6-promise

I'm using Geocodio, it is callback based geocoding. I have an array of objects, each has a restaurant object nested in it. See example below:

```
{
    id: 0, title: "Half off all pizzas", 
    details:"Carry out only, all-day", 
    days: ["Monday", "Tuesday"],
    restaurant: {
        name: "Papa John's", 
        addressOne: "2937 Greenville Ave", 
        city: "Dallas", 
        state: "TX", 
        zip: 75206
    } 
}
```

I currently am mapping over the array of objects to pass each restaurant's address into a geocoding function. I want to then add a property to that object called location, which will contain the results of the geocoding. However, the element is being returned before the results of the function can be passed into the object. See below:

```
generateCoordinates (req, res, next) {
    var newDeals = deals.map((cur, ind, arr) => {
        location = new Promise (function(resolve, reject) { 
            geocodio.get('geocode',  {q: `${cur.restaurant.addressOne}, 
                ${cur.restaurant.city}, ${cur.restaurant.state}, 
                ${cur.restaurant.zip}`}, function(err, response) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err)
                        throw err;
                    }
                    else {
                        var result = JSON.parse(response);
                        let obj = result.results[0].location;
                        // console.log(obj);
                        resolve(obj)
                    }
                }
            )}).then((obj) => {
                cur.location = obj;
                console.log(cur)
                return cur;
            })
        return cur;
        // console.log(newDeals)
    }) 
    res.status(200).send(newDeals)
},
```

There's a good chance I'm misusing the Promise constructor here. The console.log in the .then shows each element having the location property properly added, but the response and console.log(newDeals) shows the value as "Promise".

How can I set the location property of each element in the array?

Comment: No, you are not missusing it, but you should return the promise and use `Promise.all` on the returned array.

Comment: Does `geocodio.get()` return a `Promise`?  You might be able to avoid the explicit Promise construction if it does.

Comment: You might not need to manually create a Promise. If you are on node 8+ you could use `util.promisify`  that lifts callback style functions to promise based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you shouldn't do anything in the async callback but to call `resolve` or `reject`. Especially you should not `throw`!

The `return cur` doesn't exactly work, because it happens before the promise will be resolved. You'll need to return the promise from the `map` callback and then wait for all the promises in the array using `Promise.all`. When that is finally fulfilled, only then you can send the response. Also don't forget to send an appropriate response when an error happens.

```
generateCoordinates (req, res, next) {
    var newDeals = deals.map((cur, ind, arr) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            geocodio.get('geocode', {
                q: `${cur.restaurant.addressOne},
                    ${cur.restaurant.city}, ${cur.restaurant.state},
                    ${cur.restaurant.zip}`
            }, (err, response) => {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else resolve(response);
            });
        }).then(response => {
            var result = JSON.parse(response);
            let obj = result.results[0].location;
            cur.location = obj;
            console.log(cur)
            return cur;
        })
    );
    Promise.all(newDeals).then(results => {
        res.status(200).send(results);
    }, err => {
        res.status(500); // or whatever
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, your code will not work. You need to return the promise inside of the map, otherwise you get an array filled with `undefined`

Comment: @KarimHKyler I've used an arrow function with a concise body which does implicitly return the promise. Notice the "missing" braces.

Comment: Wow. You guys are geniuses. Thank you for the help! This worked. Response comes back with the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to return an array of values?  you almost have it, but you need to wait for the Promises to resolve. something like this:

```
generateCoordinates (req, res, next) {
    var newDeals = deals.map((cur, ind, arr) => {
        return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) { 
            geocodio.get('geocode',  {q: `${cur.restaurant.addressOne}, 
            ${cur.restaurant.city}, ${cur.restaurant.state}, 
            ${cur.restaurant.zip}`}, function(err, response) {
                if (err) {
                   return reject(err);
                }
                else {
                    var result = JSON.parse(response);
                    let obj = result.results[0].location;
                    // console.log(obj);
                    resolve(obj)
                }
            }
        )}).then((obj) => {
            cur.location = obj;
            console.log(cur)
            return cur;
        });

    //newDeals is an array of promises at this point
    Promise.all(newDeals).then(results => {
      //results here is a value resolved from your promise above
      return res.status(200).send(results)
    }).catch(er r=> {
    //handle errror
    });
},
```

What I am doing is using map here to create an array of promises. Then using `Promise.all` to wait for the promises to finish. whatever you return from the `then` block inside your `map` will end up as an array in the `then` block of `Promise.all`. If you reject any of the promises it will automatically catch them in the `Promise.all`

Comment: This worked. Initially thought it wasn't working because I didn't notice that you had returned the new Promise. Thank you!